# Get the id of the latest record in group by with linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to get the latest record for a group in linq but I want the id, not the date as sometimes the dates can be exactly the same as other records.

The following code gives me the key and the last date

```
var latestPositions = from bs in Scan
     group bs by bs.Asset into op
     select new
     {
        Asset = op.Key,
        LastSeen = op.Max(x => x.LastSeen)
      };
```

Returns something like this...

```
Asset      LastSeen
BS1        2020-05-10
BS2        2020-07-10
```

Which is what I need, but I then need to get to the rest of the data from that table row, but if I join it on the two columns I can get multiple rows, is there a way for me to return the id column in the group by, so I can join on that?

Thanks

Comment: var latestPosition = Scan.OrderByDescending(x => x.LastSeen).GroupBy(x => x.Asset).Select(x => new {Asset = x.Key, LastSeen = x.First().LastSeen}).ToList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GroupBy cannot help here because of SQL limitation. But you can write workaround

```
var latestPositions = from bs in Scan
   where !Scan.Any(s => s.Asset == bs.Asset && s.LastSeen > bs.LastSeen)
   select bs;
```

But I have to mention that fastest way is using window functions which are not available in EF Core:

```
SELET 
   sc.Id
FROM (
   SELECT 
      s.Id,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.Asset ORDER BY s.LastSeen DESC) AS RN
   FROM Scan s
) sc
WHERE sc.RN == 1
```

But there is exists EF Core extension [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) which makes it possible via LINQ (I assume that Asset is just ID, not a navigation property)

```
var queryRn = from bs in Scan
   select new 
   {
      Entity = bs,
      RN = Sql.Ext.RowNumber().Over()
        .PartitionBy(bs.Asset).OrderByDesc(bs.LastSeen).ToValue()
   };

 // switch to alternative translator
 queryRn = queryRn.ToLinqToDB();

 var latestPositions = from q in queryRn
    where q.RN == 1
    select q.Entity;
```

Comment: I think you're missing the very common LINQ approach to this problem, which jdweng included as a comment.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, if you think it is acceptable approach - go ahead. I see slow workaround even non translatable to SQL.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior With all my respect, you and jdweng both miss the fact that   LINQ to Entities is not the same as LINQ to Objects. And what  works in L2O or even in L2E(EF6) does not necessarily work in L2E(EF Core). In fact many `GroupBy` constructs (basically all except simple key/aggregates) currently do not work in EF Core.

Comment: You two are absolutely correct. I'm still working with EF6 and had no idea that EF Core lacked the ability to handle GroupBy/FirstOrDefault constructs.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior, check generated SQL in EF6. I think you have whole table client side evaluation.

Comment: From what I can tell, that was done in EF Core 2.1, and abandoned in EF Core 3 as a breaking change. I don't think any of the .NET Framework EF versions ever did automatic client-side evaluation.

Comment: Actually EF Core 2.1 do client side evaluation and then in EF Core 3 they disabled that by default because of hidden performance penalty. As I know this query is not translatable to the SQL, that's why I'm asking for  double check in EF 6

Comment: Your first answer didn't work, so I went with the extension, it created a query exactly the same as the one I had in the first place. Nice extension wish it could work with an in-memory db for unit testing

Comment: @NoseBagUK, `linq2db` will never work with in-memory db. Even worse EF team wants to deprecate this storage, but community claims that it is handy. So they has to support this variant. I think better is to setup SQLite in-memory and this query will work.

Comment: So is there any updated on how to this with EF Core 5.0 and using Linq To Entities, Ie I want to get the latest row for each group in one SQL  (Not EF6 and not L2O).
I know I can do it in 2 queries, get Max Date first, then get corresponding rows, but is there not a EF Core way to do it in one query

Answer (score 0):

[I think I did what you wanted above and I wrote the full code on this link](https://howtodevelop.net/article/30/nested-sql-in-linq-get-lastest-record-for-a-group)

If it's not what you want, can you write what you want a little more clearly.

```
var temp = from l in list
       group l by l.Asset into lg
       orderby lg.Key
       select new { Asset = lg.Key, LastSeen = lg.Max(x => x.LastSeen), ID = lg.Where(x => x.LastSeen == lg.Max(y => y.LastSeen)).Single().ID };
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work because the LastSeen is not always unique for the same asset

Answer (score 0):

So every `Scan` has a property `Asset`, a DateTime property `LastSeen`, and zero or more other properties.

**Requirement**: given a sequence of Scans, give me per Asset (all or some of the ) properties of the LastSeen Scan.

The following will do the trick:

```
var lastSeenScan = dbContext.Scans.GroupBy(scan => scan.Asset,

    // parameter resultSelector: take every Asset, and all Scans that have this Asset value
    // and order these Scans by descending value of lastSeen:
    (asset, scansWithThisAssetValue) => scansWithThisAssetValue
        .OrderByDescending(scan => scan.LastSeen)

        // Select the scan properties that you plan to use.
        // Not needed if you want the complete Scan
        .Select(scan => new
        {
            Id = scan.Id,
            Operator = scan.Operator,
            ...
        })

        // and keep only the First one, which is the Last seen one:
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

In words: divide your table of of Scans into groups of scans that have the same value for property Asset. Order all scans in each group by descending value of LastSeen. This will make the Scan that has last been seen the first one.

From all scans in the group select only the properties that you plan to use, and take the first one.

Result: for every used Asset, you get the (selected properties of the) scan that has the highest value of LastSeen.

Comment: Came back to this question and decided to try a few solutions to see if any where better than the one I had. Unfortunately, EF can't translate this into a query, thanks anyway